# insert multiple rows from select statement in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I have a table that need to be migrate to new table.

Table A migrates to Table B

Table A

```
| ID   | type |

| A1   |  A   |
| A2   |  B   |
| A3   |  A   |
| A4   | both |
| A5   |  A   |
```

and I hope the table B will look like this

Table B

```
| ID   | FKA  |  TYPE |

| B1   |  A1  |   Aa  |
| B2   |  A2  |   Bb  |
| B3   |  A3  |   Aa  |
| B4   |  A4  |   Aa  |
| B5   |  A4  |   Bb  |
| B6   |  A5  |   Aa  |
```

If you realized that if type is both, it will insert two times in table B from table A.

**FKA is the foreign key from table A

Currently I do 3 queries

query 1:

```
insert into tableB
select sequence1.nextVal, ID, 
(case
when type = 'A' then 'Aa'
when type = 'B' then 'Bb'
when type = 'both' then 'Aa'
else NULL
end
) from tableA
```

query 2

```
insert into tableB
select sequence1.nextVal, ID, 
(case
when type = 'both' then 'Bb'
else 'laterdelete'
end
) from tableA
```

query 3

```
delete from tableB where type = 'laterdelete'
```

thanks guys

Comment: Which rdbms? I think you could do with a mapping table or with a sub query embedded in the query that emulates a mapping table.

Comment: I think i use oracle RDBMS. If what I understand is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the rdbms is Oracle.  You might want to create a table (e.g. "tablemapping") with these values

```
 FieldFrom FieldTo
 A         Aa
 B         Bb
 both      Aa
 both      Bb
```

So you could do just:

```
 Insert into tableB
 select sequence1.nextval, ID, FieldTo
    FROM tableA a 
         join tablemapping m 
           on a.type=m.fieldFrom
```

If you don't want to have a mapping table you can simulate one.

```
 Insert into tableb
 select sequence1.nextval, ID, FieldTo
    FROM tableA a 
         join (
               select 'both'  as FieldFrom,  'Ab'  as FieldTo from dual
                Union all
               select 'both'  as FieldFrom,  'Bb'  as FieldTo from dual
                Union all
               select 'A'  as FieldFrom,  'Aa'  as FieldTo from dual
                Union all
               select 'B'  as FieldFrom,  'Bb'  as FieldTo from dual
              ) tablemapping m 
           on a.type=m.fieldFrom
```

Comment: I dont really understand about mapping table. but I will try later. But my table consist or millions of query, will it effect the performance?

Comment: It might be (we'd have to see indexes and execution plan). However it's still just one access to tableA and one insert in tableB.

Comment: tablemapping  is bridge table? and what im trying to say earlier was. would it effect my performance because there is millions of data in table original. though i still haven't try your method and will get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: Yes, "tablemapping" is just the name I gave to the bridge table.For the performance, that's the only way I could find when your big table has to be read just once.

Comment: @Aimran_Ramil hi,  had you the possibility to test my method? Did you experience a performance issue?

Comment: Any feedback on my proposal?

Comment: first of all sorry for the lateness, I recently change workplace. 
thank you for the follow up, much appreciated.

when I follow exactly your query, it returns 0 row inserted. 
so I changed
select sequence1.nextval, ID, FieldTo
to
select sequence1.nextval, ID, type
and change
a.Id=m.fieldFrom
to
a.type=m.fieldFrom
the result came as all the type = BOTH
is enter as 
| B4   |  A4  |   both |
| B5   |  A4  |   both |
when it should be 
| B4   |  A4  |   Aa  |
| B5   |  A4  |   Bb  |
did I query your sql wrongly?

Comment: The error was mine.  You have corrected the join condition (the right one was: a.type=m.fieldFrom) but it should have been the only modification to do.  Check if my edited query is returning the desired result.

Comment: yeay. thank you very much. and I pretty much understand what you had done. the join on mapping table based on tablea.type with tablemapping.fieldfrom(both,A,B). you just shorten my 3 query into one query :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use union in your first query to achieve the desired result in tableB.
Query would be as given below:

```
insert into tableB
select sequence1.nextVal, ID, 
(case
when type = 'A' then 'Aa'
when type = 'B' then 'Bb'
when type = 'both' then 'Aa'
else NULL
end
) from tableA
UNION
select sequence1.nextVal, ID, 
(case
when type = 'A' then 'Aa'
when type = 'B' then 'Bb'
when type = 'both' then 'Bb'
else NULL
end
) from tableA
```

The above query will insert Aa and Bb in tableB when type is both in tableA.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the two calls to the sequence. It is going to generate twice the same value for  the same record?

Comment: I tried this query. I guess @Insac is right. It is going to generate twice

Comment: with error SQL Error: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Comment: you can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) instead of sequence

Comment: wouldn't it add start from 1 everytime run the query?

Comment: Can I suggest a slight revision of this approach? `insert into tableB
select sequence1.nextVal, ID, newv from
(
select  ID, 
(case
when type = 'A' then 'Aa'
when type = 'B' then 'Bb'
when type = 'both' then 'Aa'
else NULL
end
) newv from tableA
UNION ALL
select  ID, 'Bb' as newv
 from tableA
where type='both' 
) `. It allows you to use the sequence, it avoids the duplicate check on the the big table (UNION vs UNION ALL) and, if the table is parittioned by type, or if there's an index and "both" is just on a small subset, it might avoid to read twice fully the big table.

Comment: I will try your suggestion when I have time to recreate the environment. thanks in advance @Insac